# Scrolling through tab view that contains YouTube shorts causes wrong video to play

Tags: html, ios, swift, swiftui, youtube

I have a YouTube view that displays a YouTube video in full screen. The struct is made to auto play when it appears, pause on tap, and has other features. When I put a bunch of these views in a vertical tab view and scroll through sometimes the wrong video that is not showing plays instead of the one that is currently displayed.

But sometimes it works just fine. But in most cases if I am scrolling down the next video will play and I can hear its audio while the current video is paused. Or if I am scrolling up then the previous video will play while the current video is paused. The 2 things that control whether the video auto plays are: in the onAppear isPlaying is toggled to true (this only works is the video has already been rendered and the user scrolls back to it), the second is in the web view did Finish function where `webView.evaluateJavaScript("clickReady()", completionHandler: nil)` is run to auto play the video when the video is ready.

But this second case only runs `if self.parent.viewIsShowing {` which is another bool that is true when the view is showing and then false when the view disappears. Because of this I'm not sure why the wrong video that isn't showing in the tab view plays and not the currently displayed one.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import UIKit

struct AllVideoView: View {
    @State private var selected = ""
    @State private var arr = ["-q6-DxWZnlQ", "Bp3iu47RRJQ", "lXJdgDjw1Ks", "It3ecCpuzgc", "7WNJjr8QM1w"]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom, .top])
            TabView(selection: $selected){
                ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ id in
                    SingleVideoView(link: id).tag(id)
                }
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: true), height: widthOrHeight(width: false))
            }
            .offset(x: -10.5)
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: false), height: widthOrHeight(width: true))
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var viewIsShowing = false
    @State private var isVideoPlaying = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            
            SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, viewIsShowing: $viewIsShowing)

            Button("", action: {}).disabled(true)
            
            Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isVideoPlaying.toggle()
                }
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onDisappear {
            isVideoPlaying = false
            viewIsShowing = false
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewIsShowing = true
            isVideoPlaying = true
        }
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var viewIsShowing: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        var jsString = """
                isPlaying = \((isPlaying) ? "true" : "false");
                watchPlayingState();
            """
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            if self.parent.viewIsShowing {
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("clickReady()", completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = false;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        
            function clickReady() {
                player.playVideo();
            }
            
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        
        </script>
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    if width {
        return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
    } else {
        return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you can make the selectedTab binding for the tabview into an environment variable and then in the video view you can check if the link parameter matches the environment variable for the selected tab. In doing so the video will only play if it is the currently selected tab. Since the onAppear method executes faster than the selectedTab environment variable changes then the onAppear won't work all the time. To ensure the video always plays add in an onChange with the exact same code as the onAppear to play the video. So for example:

```
    .onAppear {
        if viewModel.selected == link {
            viewIsShowing = true
            isVideoPlaying = true
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: viewModel.selected, perform: { _ in
        if viewModel.selected == link {
            viewIsShowing = true
            isVideoPlaying = true
        }
    })
```